# SQL: Is there a way to exclude duplicate results if a condition is met

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to build a query that will search for a certain user and the most recent job they were associated with. I want to only pull the most recent date but some users have two jobs associated with the same date. Is there a way to only pull one of those while not excluding that result if it was a user's only job?

For example

```
User    Job    Date

1      Chef    7/13/21    
1      Server  7/13/21
2      Server  7/3/21
3      Chef    7/1/21
```

Desired result:

```
User    Job    Date    

1      Chef    7/13/21    
2      Server  7/3/21
3      Chef    7/1/21
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes, but data you posted as example doesn't reflect what you're saying because for `user = 1` both jobs have same date.

Anyway, here's one option how to do that: use one of analytic functions (I used `row_number`; `rank` might also be an option) to "rank" rows partitioned by user & sorted by date, and then fetch the one with the lowest rank.

Sample data till line #6; query begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with test (cuser, job, datum) as
  2    (select 1, 'chef'  , date '2021-07-13' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'server', date '2021-07-13' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'server', date '2021-07-03' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'chef'  , date '2021-07-01' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select cuser, job, datum,
  9       row_number() over (partition by cuser order by datum desc) rn
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select cuser, job, datum
 13  from temp
 14  where rn = 1;

    CUSER JOB    DATUM
--------- ------ ----------
        1 chef   07/13/2021
        2 server 07/03/2021
        3 chef   07/01/2021

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `keep` `dense_rank`

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions

```
select user, date, 
       MIN(job) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date)
from   table
group by user, date
```

A rough example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14ee4d/2
Now this is not quite deterministic as when there are two jobs on the same date you need to specify how to sort them.   If your date column includes time then you should be OK